# wxPython - lacking grid class?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

When trying to do what is described [here.](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-an-introduction-to-grids/) I can't find the grid class. This is my import:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
```

And wx.grid is underlined as red (I'm using Eclipse) and it says:

> Unresolved import: gridlib Unused import: gridlib

I'm using `wxPython 3.0`

Comment: It works fine for me. what does it say if you only use `import wx.grid`?

Comment: @Pphoenix `Unresolved import: wx.grid`
`Unused import: wx.grid`

Comment: The rest of wx works just fine, not sure why only grid doesn't import. I can even see the grid.py file.

Comment: I guess that the wx.grid isn't installed. Try re-installing and see if it works :)

Comment: I reinstalled `wxPython3.0-win64-py27 64-bit Python 2.7` twice, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you are running python 2.7 64-bit? You might be running python 2.7 32bit on a 64bit machine?

Comment: yes I used the x64 installer, I even re-downloaded it 3 times

Comment: ok..I took out the wx folder from the wx-3.0-msw folder and deleted wx.pth, now it works just fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56881/discussion-between-pphoenix-and-bogomil).

Comment: was your wx-3.0-msw in you pythonpath?